# Proving monotonicity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

I would like to prove the following: "If $f$ is a differentiable function on an open interval and has no local extremum, then $f$ is monotone."

I have seen some questions that asks the same thing in this website, but the answers didn't seem clear to me. Also, since the differentiability condition is given, I would like to make use of it to prove the proposition.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe consider the related (and stronger) statement: if $f$ is continuous and injective then it is monotone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is not monotone on the interval $(a,b)$.  Since it isn't nondecreasing, there are $c_1,c_2$ in that interval with $c_1 < c_2$ and $f(c_1) > f(c_2)$. By the Mean Value Theorem, there is $c$ in the interval with
$$f'(c) = \dfrac{f(c_2)-f(c_1)}{c_2 - c_1} < 0$$
Similarly, since it isn't nonincreasing, there is $d$ in the interval with 
$f'(d) > 0$.

Case 1: $c < d$.

Since $f$ is continuous on $[c,d]$, it attains a minimum on the interval $[c,d]$.  That minimum can't be at $c$ because $f'(c) < 0$, and can't be at $d$ because $f'(d) > 0$, so it must be at some point $e$ with $c < e < d$.  Then $e$ is a local maximum of $f$.

Case 2: $d < c$.

By a similar argument, the maximum of $f$ on the interval $[d,c]$ must be at some $e$ with $d < e < c$, and this is a local maximum of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple. As it is given that the function has no local extremum in the given open interval, $f'\neq 0$ at any point in the interval. So either $f'$ is negative on the entire interval or it is positive on the entire interval. This implies either $f$ is monotonically decreasing or monotonically increasing on the entire interval.

Comment: Wrong.  A point where $f' = 0$ is not necessarily a local extremum. It could, for example, be an inflection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can readily recognize a counterexample of your argument. If f(x)=x^3, then f has no local extremum in (-1,1) but f'(0)=0.